# Continuous multicast traffic from my router

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, multicast, logs

I'm using an iptables firewall on my local Linux server. The log tells me that there is a continuous multicast on the network by my router (Fritz box). Is this a normal behaviour. Should I allow this traffic?

```
[633912.348130] IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
[634912.348130] IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
[635037.322691] IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
[635287.169456] IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is IGMP traffic, which unless you know why you'd want it, can be safely ignored.

The `224.0.0.1` multicast subnet is defined as being for all hosts on the network segment. (See [Notable IPv4 multicast addresses (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Notable_IPv4_multicast_addresses).)

Protocol 2 (See [List of IP protocol numbers (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers)) is IGMP, the [Internet Group Management Protocol (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol).

Essentially, your router is asking if there are any other multicast-capable routers on the subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what that traffic specifically is, in general for IPv4 multicast can most likely be ignored. For IPv6 multicast is totally necessary, as that's how router advertisements and other such things work in IPv6.

Specific things in IPv4 do use multicast, so you'll need to pass that traffic if you want those things to work. `wireshark` can probably help identify the traffic.